# tictactoe game variable not declared in the scope

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe

Hello I am new to c++ and I wanted to build a tictactoe game, but when I compile the game it gives me always this error that my variable was not declared in the scope. Then I tried to make square as a global variable but that gave me to errors.

Can anybody help me in this?

```
include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void Game();
void Spielerfeld();

void Game(){
        int player;
        int choice;
        char mark;

        Spielerfeld();
        do{

            cout << "Wer ist als erstes in der Reihe\n" << choice;
            player = 1;
            cout << "Player:" << player << "Gebe eine nummer ein";
            cin >> choice;
            mark = (player);'X';'O';
            if(choice == 1 && square[1] == '1')
                square[1] == mark;
            else if(choice == 2 && square[2] == '2')
                square[2] = mark;
            else if(choice == 3 && square[3] == "2")
                square[3] = mark;
            else if(choice == 4 && square[4] == '4')
                sqaure[4] = mark;
            else if(choice == 5 && square[5] ==  "5")
                sqaure[5] == mark;
            else if(choice == 6 && square[6] ==  "6")
                sqaure[6] == mark;
            else if(choice == 7 && square[7] ==  "7")
                sqaure[7] == mark;
            else if(choice == 8 && square[8] ==  "8")
                sqaure[8] == mark;
            else if(choice == 9 && square[9] ==  "9")
                sqaure[9] == mark;
            }while(choice == 9);
}


 void Spielerfeld(){
    int square[10] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    int i;
    for(i=0; i<10; i++){
        cout << square[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << square[1] << "|" << square[2] << "|" << sqaure[3];
    cout << "-----------|--------";
    cout << square[4] << "|" << square[5] << "|" << sqaure[6];
    cout << "-----------|--------";
    cout << square[7] << "|" << square[8] << "|" << sqaure[9];
 }

int main(){
    Spielerfeld();``
    Game();
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you added a) the exact compiler error messages b) your attempt at making squares global. However, it's probably easier to make it a variable in main and pass it to the other two functions

Comment: You're using `square` within `Game()` although it's a local variable in `Spielerfeld()`.

Comment: Sry i forgot that. that are the errors                                                                                                     tictactoe.cpp:31:5: error: ‘sqaure’ was not declared in this scope
     sqaure[6] == mark;                                                                                                                tictactoe.cpp:49:51: error: ‘sqaure’ was not declared in this scope
   cout << square[1] << "|" << square[2] << "|" << sqaure[3]

Comment: According to the classics, a properer Tic Tac Toe program [looks something like this](https://ideone.com/k4xRds).

Comment: thanks bro that was really helpful my game works.

Comment: @user4581301 lol, doesn't beat an evening of good ol "global thermonuclear war" though.

Comment: @Zodiac Your first comment: We cannot see line numbers. Please add pointers to what and where these lines are.

Answer (score 2):

1) Square is a local variable in Spielerfeld() function and it destroy after end of function so you can not use it.

2) you defined "Square" as a built in array and the built in array elements start with zero index. So when you want to access to first element you should use Square[0].

I defined Square as a global variable and modify your code.
Now try it.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
void Game();
void Spielerfeld();
int square[9] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9 };

void Game() 
{
    int player = 0;
    int choice = 0;
    char mark = 0;

    Spielerfeld();
    do {

        cout << "Wer ist als erstes in der Reihe\n" << choice;
        player = 1;
        cout << "Player:" << player << "Gebe eine nummer ein";
        cin >> choice;
        mark = (player); 'X'; 'O';
        if (choice == 1 && square[0] == 1)
            square[0] = mark;
        else if (choice == 2 && square[1] == 2)
            square[1] = mark;
        else if (choice == 3 && square[2] == 2)
            square[2] = mark;
        else if (choice == 4 && square[3] == 4)
            square[3] = mark;
        else if (choice == 5 && square[4] == 5)
            square[4] = mark;
        else if (choice == 6 && square[5] == 6)
            square[5] = mark;
        else if (choice == 7 && square[6] == 7)
            square[6] = mark;
        else if (choice == 8 && square[7] == 8)
            square[7] = mark;
        else if (choice == 9 && square[8] == 9)
            square[8] = mark;
    } while (choice == 9);
}


void Spielerfeld() {

    int i;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) 
    {
        cout << square[i] << endl;
    }

    cout << square[0] << "|" << square[1] << "|" << square[2];
    cout << "-----------|--------";
    cout << square[3] << "|" << square[4] << "|" << square[5];
    cout << "-----------|--------";
    cout << square[6] << "|" << square[7] << "|" << square[8];

}

int main() 
{
    Spielerfeld();
    Game();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple issue you have. In C++ there's a difference between the `==` operator and `=` operator. Simply put, `==` is used for equality *comparison* and `=` used for variable assignment. All of those lines that say `square[i] == mark;` should instead say `square[i] = mark;`